# Remove the recursive directory in Unix ( Unlimited Child Directories )

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

How to delete the recursive directory in Solaris.

Directory Structure : **SourceCode/unit_test_cases.**

The command 
**cp -rf SourceCode/ SourceCode/unit_test_cases/** : created a recursive directory.

Directory Structure looks like below

```
SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode/unit_test_cases/
```

I know "rm -rf SourceCode" is to delete recursively. But this command gives the error File Name too long. This is due to unlimited child directories recursively created.
So am not able delete the directories.

I tried this in Ubuntu, It is smart that it determines the cyclic recursion and breaks @ some depth, But Solaris seems to be dumb in this case.
Can anybody help me

Answer (score 2):

It is simply

```
  rm -rf PATHS
```

where PATHS is one or more PATH to be removed (it's enough SourceCode if you want to remove that dir completely).

Comment: or only SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode if you want to delete the "recursive" hierarchy you've just created

Comment: not able to do so.. It is giving an error "Filenames too long"

Comment: I've tried myself of course... it happened that cp -rf stopped with that error, but I was able anyway to do rm -rf on both SouceCode/ and SourceCode/unit_test_cases/SourceCode. I've tried it on Solaris. Try then with the inode: ls -di SourceCode, then use the inode number with rm -i Inode --- EDIT: this won't work, it seems at least on Solaris, the dir Inode is not like a file Inode...?

Comment: indeed it does not work since -i is not for "inode" but interactive, I remembered it wrong...

Comment: Needless to say, you must not do "`rm -rf SourceCode/*`". Do not use the * at all!

Comment: Hi. did you get any error. I am not able to move also. It does not remove the directories. Any alternatives.?

Comment: sorry, I've tried it on Solaris as said and it was able to remove the whole tree; on GNU/Linux with GNU's cp (coreutils), it prohibits the creation of such a monster: `cp: cannot copy a directory, 'SourceCode', into itself, 'SourceCode/unit/SourceCode'` so I can't reproduce the problem, unless I go for another cp... indeed, try a different rm, ... maybe it could help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rm -r <your directory>
```

and be careful of what you are deleting.